# Xpath to CSS conversion

Tags: javascript, css, xpath, css-selectors, protractor

I have problem with conversion few particular xpath to css selectors.
Tried several approached but finally gived up :/ maybe it's specific for my testing framework (protractor) or I am doing mistake.

Could anyone please help with conversion of four below ?

```
findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="availableDomains"]/li[1]'))

pageMain.prototype.newUser = function (userId) {
    return element(by.xpath('//tbody//tr[td[contains(text(), "' + userId + '")]]'));
};

UsersPage.prototype.rowFor = function (user) {
    return element(by.xpath('//tr[@data-user="' + user.id + '"]'));
};

findElement(by.xpath('//*[@class="table table-striped"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]'))
```

Comment: `#availableDomains li:first-child` and css does not have contains

Comment: @epascarello What is equivalent to contains in css ? I wanna build identical function as described but with css selector. Could you provide some solution ?

Comment: There is no contains...

Comment: @epascarello so in such case I am convicted on xpath ? I can't believe ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Some things are still easier to get via XPath*, despite the [recommendations](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/style-guide.md#never-use-xpath) not to use XPath location technique. You can though still approach this problem differently using different location mechanisms:

```
element(by.xpath('//*[@id="availableDomains"]/li[1]'))
```

would be converted to the following CSS selector:

```
$('#availableDomains li:first-child')
```

---

Instead of:

```
element(by.xpath('//tbody//tr[td[contains(text(), "' + userId + '")]]'))
```

the [`by.cssContainingText`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) can be used:

```
element(by.cssContainingText("tbody tr td", userId));
```

---

This part:

```
element(by.xpath('//tr[@data-user="' + user.id + '"]'));
```

can be converted to:

```
$('tr[data-user="' + user.id + '"]');
```

---

As a bonus, if you want to enforce the "never ever use XPaths" rule, there is a [`eslint-plugin-protractor` ESLint plugin](https://github.com/alecxe/eslint-plugin-protractor) that would warn you about the `by.xpath()` usage in your codebase.

Comment: how about such selector : by.xpath('//*[@class="table table-striped"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[5]') ?  :)

Comment: @Michal sure, `$(".table.table-striped > tbody > tr:first-child > td:nth-child(5)");` should work.